# Modify data in MSAccess before passing on to SQL Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, pass-through, bridge

I have set up an Access database with a linked table to an SQL table. I've created a query in Access off the linked table.  I have shipping software that i've set up to export data to the Access query and it successfully gets passed on to the SQL Table. So far, so good.

Now to the issue.  The "weight" column in the SQL table has an "implied" 4 decimal places. So when I export a weight of "1", it shows up in the SQL table as ".0001".  I need to multiply the weight by 10000 in order to get it to show up as "1.0000" in the SQL table.

I've tried modifying the Query's SELECT statement to do the math on that column but I get a "Cannot Update Field" error out of the ODBC driver.

Is there a way to make this happen?  I'm not using MS Access at all (other than to create the .mdb file). Just using the .mdb file as a bridge between the shipping application and the SQL table.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: What is the dataType of the weight column?

Comment: can you post the query that you tried and "didn't work".  I can't imagine that multiplying and int by 10,000 to get it to import into a float correctly is the only way to get it to work?  Are you sure there isn't something else going on?

Comment: It's a simple select statement inside a query: `SELECT PkgWgt, PkgCost, TrkNum FROM LinkedTable`. This works fine. But if I do this: `SELECT PkgWgt*10000, PkgCost, TrkNum FROM LinkedTable` then I get an ODBC error _Field is not updateable_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296097/886591) which looks very similar to what you are looking for.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296097/886591

Comment: This is a freshly created mdb file. The linked table doesn't need refreshed. There are three primary key fields and all are included in the query. The field i'm trying to multiply isn't a primary key field. The matter is now moot since i got the db admin to multiply the field in his script that moves the data to its final destination. I will mark this as answered. Thanks.